# Android: restart or refresh a LiveWallpaper after preference change

Tags: android, preferences, wallpaper

Is it posible to restart a wallpaper after a preference is changed?

I'm thinking I can use this to see the event. But I'm not sure how to update the wallpaper afterwards, if the wallpaper is already running.

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs) {

}
```

Basically, I want to have a wallpaper with a preference that changes a bitmap being used in the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, and yes, you've got the right idea. :-)  Your best place to start is to look at the "second" (resource) cube wallpaper SDK example, which changes its model (cube vs. dodecahedron) in onSharedPreferenceChanged, based on a user preference change.

In that example, they don't mess with the drawing queue--just alter the data that gets used, but I don't see why you couldn't remove callbacks to your runnable and then restart your drawing process, if that better suits your purpose.

Comment: This page is now the top Google result for ""second" (resource) cube wallpaper SDK example" - I know it is 5 years later, but if you could recall any specifics for the link / technique you are referencing, I would be very grateful!